# What happened to Low quality posts?

Tags: discussion, review

I noticed today when I came to review it had 303 low quality posts. That's an amazing number, more than I've ever seen on any other site.. What happened to get so many?

[image]

All the posts appear to be questions.. maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: I was offline all day. Sorry ^^

Comment: @LuisAlvarado LOL

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I wish I had a diamond. ;) http://i.stack.imgur.com/wpItH.png

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is obsolete I guess.